# Display recurring events via sharepoint search

Tags: sharepoint-search, recurring-events

I'm challengend to display the next occurrence of recurring events in a search results webpart (with a custom display template) in a SharePoint 2013 (SP1 not applied) environment.

So far, I tested several crawled properties: ows_EventDate, ows_q_DATE_StartDate, ows_RecSstartDate and several more, without success: ows_EventDate always contains the start date of the first occurrence, and the others were always empty. Of course a full crawl has been done between reconfigurations.

For Testing purpose, I created managed properties (type DateTime) for each single crawled property above, and displayed them in a custom Display template for the search results webpart, to visualize the Contents of the properties.

So, do you have any hints how to Access the next / current start date for recurring Events via SharePoint Search?

Is it possible to create a calculated column on the calendar entry containing the next occurrence start date, which is then crawled by search?

Thank you very much in andvance,
Martin

Answer (score 1):

Recurring events can not be searched. (Well, the first occurence will be crawled and show as search result, no recurrence will.)

The reason being that recurring events are not physically existing in SharePoint and thus will not be crawled by search. (Technically, the first occurence is the only one existing, hence *it* will be crawled and *it* will be searchable...)